# What happens from the moment we press a key on the keyboard, until it appears in your word document

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, hardware

This question was in my job interview.. I just to see whether I gave all the details...

Comment: is it a wired or wireless keyboard? :-)

Comment: Hint: the interviewer was probably not interested in hearing a canned response. The question was probably meant to find out how much you know about the different levels of a computer, how much interest you have in each part. Answering with a canned response is totally missing the point.

Comment: Most answers here omit the most important detail: If the stress fuse (aka. deadline fuse) is above a manufacturer set threshold, the CPU will randomly flip a bit in RAM. Just to mess with you. On some operating systems more sophisticated support is available and the stress fuse threshold can be selectively increased, factoring in presence of backup (connected storage media and network services), time of day (multiple bit flips after 3AM!), general mood (speech recognition of swear words via. detected microphones) and importance of task (full email search).

Comment: I first would mention the fact that it won't appears in my"word" doc,since I do not own a license to run Word, so I do not run it at all(nor the O.S. that normally hosts it);the Q is already "biased" to a specific O.S.,making people think the Q is also about how MS Windows (win32) handles hardware events and delivers them to app having focus... but the "letter" won't appear in Word before it performs its own things,so this is for hardware+win32+MS Word internals expert...? I would refuse to answer correctly to such a badly made Q(and likely this is why I am unemployed currently:D)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: LOL, I think the emphasis in this question was the low level part of the answer... as soon as I got to the application layer he actually stopped me :-)

Comment: Of all of the _interview_ questions I've seen on here this is the most absurd. Even if limited to a x86 based MS Windows PC made within the last 2 years there is still several optional layers that it could go through. If I was compelled to answer this question as completely and accurately as I could I could probably talk for 8 hours straight and even then I'd probably miss some stuff and don't know some (after Windows knows it has a keyboard key press there are many things that could happen before deciding that a key press event should go to an application).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- mechanical switch short-circuits pull up R1 resistor end to the ground
- a special multiplexor translates it into a message, to reduce the number of wires
- the message interpreted by a CPU embedded in the keyboard
- message translated to a USB protocol message, and modulated as a series of electric impulses of alternating voltage between zero and 5 volts
- USB receiving hub measures samples line voltage periodically
- host hub controller translates the message to data
- data enters PC thru USB bus controller, connected to PCIE bus, thru a combination of IRQ notificaitons and a DMA transfer, issued by the bus driver
- Bus driver interprets the message and forwards it along the driver stack, ultimately to an HID driver
- HID driver talks to windows, ultimately resulting in a window message sent to a window belonging to msword process
- WM_KEYDOWN is translated to WM_CHAR by DefWindowProc(). While key is down, multiple WM_CHARs may be created.
- Word application catches WM_CHAR to add another character to the document model and issue re-rendering of UI
- UI rendering engine translates unicode codepoint to graphical image by loading respective font
- graphics engine computes the new image of the whole area to avoid flicker, and puts it pixel-by-pixel to the screen

Comment: good answer. If held down after some delay the sequence repeats at a specific interval (except for the initial mechanical switch closure).  When the key is released the sequence repeats again except for the switch closure which is now a switch open and you have KEYUPS instead of KEYDOWNS.  In case you are asked mice operate on the button release not on the button closure, try it yourself press the mouse button over some object, move the mouse and release it over something else.

Comment: I'm sorry, but since you did not address the fact that since with USB the host has to ask the keyboard for new data before the keyboard can be sent to the host, your answer is inadequate.   Just kidding.  Very good.

Answer (score 12):

1. you hear a click ;) [but not necessary at this step, maybe at 10th or 20th]
2. keyboard signals to kb controller
3. controller issues an interrupt to CPU
4. OS kernel sees interrupt
5. OS kernel dispatches interrupt to corresponding driver
6. driver tells CPU to read a charcode from kb controller
7. CPU does
8. driver some way tells the kernel to post an 'KEY_DOWN' event into UI subsystem
9. kernel dispatches event
10. UI subsystem checks if there active window
11. it sends a KEY_DOWN UI event to active window

... uh.. tired :) so, after that it will dispatch a key, update window contents, and call the video driver/subsystem to draw that char

Comment: 11 is wrong. 11 is KEY_DOWN event goes to active application, as identified by active window. Let me continue. 12. application via GetMessage() main loop gets the event and dispatches it via DispatchMessage(), probably applying some translations (that's where mapping to which window the event actually goes). 13. assigned to the window even handling routine is called and from here on it is in responsibility of application. Word processor would apply the key press to the document in memory and trigger refresh to the screen so that the new document in memory is properly reflected on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, if you have an old old old old binary computer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card

Then, in the time you pressed the key, you could probably make a cup of tea!

Comment: I was once puzzled, why have they used so big holes in punch cards. The answer was amazing. The scan was not optical at all. They just used this to connect metal-to-metal switches.